# conversation+discovery java code is working

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-discovery

I am trying to run the sample java watson conversation with discovery service in my IBM account.
I have created the java app and added the service details in environment variables and tried to deploy the code  but getting below error .
please let me know what is the cause for this issue.

Preparing to start the job...
Cloning the 'master' branch from repo 'https://git.eu-gb.bluemix.net/anil.narayanaswamy002/tnchatbot.git'
Repository successfully cloned
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/moowork/gradle/gradle-node-plugin/0.12/gradle-node-plugin-0.12.pom
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/moowork/gradle/gradle-gulp-plugin/0.12/gradle-gulp-plugin-0.12.pom

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'conversation-with-discovery'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5.
  >    Required by:
  >        com.ibm.watson.wea.app:conversation-with-discovery:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT
  >   Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-backports-compat23/2.3.5/groovy-backports-compat23-2.3.5.pom'.
  >   peer not authenticated
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.217 secs

Finished: FAILED

Comment: What kind of maven artifactory are you using? Is it the maven central? Could it be there is some problem to get this dependency from there? I would try to get the missing dependency and install it manually to your local maven repo and run it again.

Comment: i am deploying the code in IBM cloud , I was able to deploy the same code successfully few months back but now its not working.'

Comment: I would try to use the latest repo from github and check the pom.xml file - what kind of repositories are there specified. Also I would try to build the project localy to see all the maven dependencies are resolved ok - to see whether the problem is in the build process on the cloud or whether the problem is in the build of the project. (you might also want to create an issue in the github project itself, that way you could get the answer from some developer involved).

Comment: Thanks Michal for your response, i have opened a issue with watson java team.